# Create dictionary with keys as file names values are content

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key-value

I have 4 files, and I created the list from the names of csv files:

```
file_names['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
```

And in each file I have more than 6-7 columns. I can get column names with the following code:

```
for x in file_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(path + x)
    print(list(df.columns))
```

it works fine, but how can I create (not manually) a dictionary with a for loop where the keys are `file_names` and values are `list(df.columns)`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension, `nrows=0` is for better performance for read only header:

```
d = {x: pd.read_csv(path + x, nrows=0).columns.tolist() for x in file_names}
```

Or loop with read header by `readline`:

```
d = {}
for x in file_names:
    with open(x) as f:
        d[x] = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 2):

First create an empty `dict` then simply have the dictionary key value be the file name and `list(df.columns)` be its value, this creates new entries in the `dict`:

```py
file_names = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']

file_data = {}

for x in file_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(path + x)
    file_data[x] = list(df.columns)
```

Comment: yes it works. Could you pleasy kindly explain how it works? becausewhen i print file_data[x] to see the content it returns me the list of column names, but when i print file_data i see key-values.(file names and columns)how it writes files names as well to dict?

Comment: So when we call the line `file_data[x] = list(df.columns)`, x (which is the file name) is the key we are creating in the `file_data` dict and list(df.columns) is the value. We are doing this for every file name (which we have called x) in file_names. These tutorials on [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) and [dicts](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) should help if you need more info.